# Error during download: "Error 403 forbidden" when updating apps from App Store in OS X

Tags: macos, mac-app-store

I'm using a MacBook Air with OS X 10.6.

I'm not able to update or download any apps from the App Store anymore. 
I tried to solve it this way but can't make it work:

> [Mac OS X 10.5: Web Sharing - "Forbidden 403" message appears instead of website content](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA25038?viewlocale=en_US)

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why do you think web sharing has to do with your inability to update app store apps?

Comment: Are any other websites affected?

Answer (score 0):

I signed out of icloud account, went to itunes preferences: advanced tab, reset warnings, and reset cache. then restarted the computer. It worked for me. Hope this helps.